# SSRS report issue

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS report runs every month. The report has title like 
"**Monthly-Stock Prediction Report-04/07/2014**". The date part in the title is dynamically added. And, the report file name in report server is **PeriodicReport.rdl**.
This report is configured such a way that every month it gets executed and sent to a XYZ department's email address in **EXCEL format**.

1) I want to change file name from **PeriodicReport.rdl** to **MontlyStockPrediction.xlsx** when the report gets sent to the XYZ Department email. Is it possible to change original report file name (=**PeriodicReport.rdl**) while sending as EXCEL file to (=**MontlyStockPrediction.xlsx**) in the email ???

2) How to put above report title (= **Monthly-Stock Prediction Report-04/07/2014**) dynamically in **Subject** of the **email** ?? Is it possible ?

Please help me on this, I will give you best wishes :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure the report name in the properties is set to MonthlyStockPrediction.

If you do not mind the datetime stamp on the subject line you can easily set in the subscription setup the subject to be Monthly-Stock Prediction Report-@ExecutionTime.

You can refer to the following article for more information on formatting the date time in the subject email:
[@ExecutionTime date format on email subject?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9339d95f-a99c-4713-9466-31591442d0ff/executiontime-date-format-on-email-subject?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: Thanks for response! But, I did not see *Report Name* attribute in Report (i.e PeriodicReport.rdl) properties.
I can only see *File Name* and *Full Path* attributes. Any more suggestion, pls ?

Comment: Are you in the report manager at all?  That tends to be easier when setting up subscriptions as well as reports.  You should be able to see the name on the first page when you manage the report.